Issue with Azure Deployment Centre failing due to MS Build
Since Monday, we are having failed CI/CD deployments through the Azure Deployment Centre (linked to BitBucket), due to the MS Build number being incorrectly specified.
Please see example configuration: Deployment Centre
We haven't changed our environment or project settings, so we cannot understand it. We even tested branching from the last successful commit and connecting to that branch in Azure Web App, but that also fails to build.
Our VS version clearly states 17.9.6, but the MS Build is showing in the Deployment Centre logs as 16.4.0. Azure Support advised that they think it is relating to this.
As a test we have also pushed our changes to a Azure DevOps Repo, but this is returning exactly the same MSBuild version (and therefore failed build).
*Successful:
Command: "C:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment with MSBuild16.
MSBuild version 17.8.3+195e7f5a3 for .NET Framework
Build started 4/10/2024 5:02:44 AM

Unsuccessful:
Command: "C:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment with MSBuild16.
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.*

Is there anyway that we can specify the MS Build number, so that it is the version that works for our system (17.8.3 - or latest 17.9.6)?
Why would this have changed without us making changes to our application?
Is there some configuration setting I am missing in the proj file, Azure or BitBucket?

MSBUILD is only supported in Bitbucket self hosted windows agent, Make sure you create a self hosted runner and install the latest MSbuild version to run your bitbucket pipeline, Reference here. In Azure Devops pipeline you can use 17.0 MSBuild version as outlined in this MS Document.
Instead of using MSBuild, You can directly use DotNetCoreCLI@2 task to deploy your web app via Azure Devops pipeline:-
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

jobs:
- job: Build
  displayName: 'Build and Publish'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restore Dependencies'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration Release'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      publishWebProjects: true
      arguments: '--configuration Release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: true

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifactName: 'publishedApp'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- job: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - download: current
    artifact: 'publishedApp'

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'xxx subscription (01xxxxxxxx2a7)'
      appType: 'webApp'
      appName: 'siliconwebapp6'
      package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'
      deploymentMethod: 'auto'

Output:-

Reference:-
Deploying .NET code to App Service using Azure Devops but SDK not found - Stack Overflow My SO answer
